# JRI REXP boolean values

Tags: java, r, rjava, jri

I want to get results from an method which is called kruskalmc.

The results in R console look like that:

```
Multiple comparison test after Kruskal-Wallis 
p.value: 0.05 
Comparisons
      obs.dif critical.dif difference  
1-2    7.65     9.425108      FALSE
1-3   14.40     9.425108       TRUE 
2-3    6.75     9.425108      FALSE
```

Now i want to get the values from the difference column.

If i try to get it in java with:

```
REXP res = re.eval("result$dif.com$difference");
```

I'll get back something like this: [BOOLi* ]

How can i iterate through in BOOLi object in java?

What i want are the values FALSE TRUE FALSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used JRI much but since no-one has answered you I'll go for it.

I could be wrong, but it seems there is no method for converting `res` to a boolean array – although there are methods for converting to `int[]`, `double[]` and `String[]`. You could convert your result to integers like this:

```
REXP res = re.eval("result$dif.com$difference");
int[] x = res.asIntArray();

for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(x[i]);
}
```

You will get back `1` representing `TRUE` values and `0` representing `FALSE`. You can convert those numbers to booleans if you want from Java then or just work with them as they are.

Not an ideal solution so I hope someone comes up with something better.

Comment: If you use `REngine` API then there is `public boolean[] isFALSE()` and `public boolean[] isTRUE()`. For obvious reasons conversions from R logicals to boolean are lossy so you have to declare how you want `NA`s treated. With the low-level JRI API using `asIntArray()` is indeed the best way to go and decide based on the int values what to do.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the issue is type conversion when exporting from `R` to `java`. Looking at part of the [documentation](http://svn.mesquiteproject.org:8080/repository/MesquiteR/trunk/MesquiteR/Source/org/rosuda/JRI/REXP.java) for JRI:

> The currently supported objects are string, integer and numeric vectors.

To give a reproducible example (from the functions own documentation):

```
require(pgirmess)
resp <-c(0.44,0.44,0.54,0.32,0.21,0.28,0.7,0.77,0.48,0.64,0.71,0.75,0.8,0.76,0.34,0.80,0.73,0.8)
categ <- as.factor(rep(c("A","B","C"),times=1,each=6))
k1 <- kruskalmc(resp, categ)
```

Then we can see that `is.logical(k1[[3]][,3]) == TRUE`:

```
> str(k1[[3]][,3])
logi [1:3] FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

while still in `R` the simplest method would seem to be converting this with

```
> as.numeric(k1[[3]][,3])
[1] 0 1 0
```

or you could send it across as character:

```
> as.character(k1[[3]][,3])
[1] "FALSE" "TRUE"  "FALSE"
```

Once in `java` you'll want to convert it back to boolean, or whatever final form you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Call:

```
survdiff(formula = model)

                                N Observed Expected (O-E)^2/E (O-E)^2/V
x[, 1]=G1:Vehicle               8        6     2.65      4.22      9.02
x[, 1]=G2:AZ13655037 15mg/kg/qd 8        0     3.35      3.35      9.02
```

Chisq= 9  on 1 degrees of freedom, p= 0.00267 
Now we want to get the values from the p. 
How can i get it in java?